# Name of the driver for derby database

Tags: java, netbeans, derby

What is the name of the driver, to be used with `derby` ?

```
      Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"); 
      // The above statement gives an exception
      // java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
      Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Tester", "username","password");
```

I am using derby that comes packed with netbeans.

Comment: Check the driver jar (and if you have it on your classpath).

Comment: derby is built in with java7.  If you are using older java, please add relevant jars to class path

Answer (score 4):

`org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver` is the class name which internally use JDBC driver.

If it does not work try with `org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver`

Comment: I get the same exception. Class name not found

Comment: @saplingPro have a look at here http://www.coderanch.com/t/471025/ORM/databases/Hibernate-cfg-xml-Eclipse  it seems problem is with ur url.

Answer (score 4):

The class used for the driver is :

class org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver

serching with jar finder : you can download **derby.jar** for example

The class you are talking about can be found in **derbyclient.jar**

Answer (score 0):

Since Java SE 6/ JDBC 4.0, you don't have to load the driver manually via Class.forName anymore. You just have to have the driver Jar on your classpath and don't have know the exact driver class name.

So just remove that line and make sure you have the driver jar on your classpath.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html

> java.sql and javax.sql Features Introduced in the JDBC 4.0 API
>
> ```
> auto java.sql.Driver discovery -- no longer need to load a java.sql.Driver class via Class.forName
> ```